# Dependency Injection in Xamarin.Android

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, xamarin.android

I am working on a Xamarin.Android project developed by another developer. I got to know that they have used **Dependancy Injection**. There is a class like this

```
 public class RemoteSupportHandler : DataAccessor<FwDataContext>, IRemoteSupportSettingHandler
{
    private RemoteSupportSetting[] _cached;

    public RemoteSupportHandler(IDatabaseController db, ILogger logger, IPerfLogger perfLogger)
       : base(db, logger, perfLogger)
    {
    }

    public async Task<RemoteSupportSetting> GetRemoteSupportDemoVideoUrlAsync()
    {

        return await WithDataContextAsync(ctx =>
        {
            return (from row in ctx.RemoteSupportSettings
                    where row.ParamName == "DEMO_VIDEO"
                    select new RemoteSupportSetting
                    {
                        ParamName = row.ParamName

                    }).FirstOrDefault();
        });
    }   
}
```

In another file, they have registered this class with `UnityContainer`. Now I want to call this `GetRemoteSupportDemoVideoUrlAsync()` method from my Activity. I know I cannot create an object using this constructor. I have no idea how I should I do this.

**Registration Code**

```
public class Registrar : IRegistrar {
    protected virtual void OnApplyInitializedRegistrations(IUnityContainer container) {
           container.RegisterType<IRemoteSupportSettingHandler, RemoteSupportHandler>(new ContainerControlledLifetimeManager());
    }
}

public interface IRegistrar
{
    void ApplySessionRegistrations(IUnityContainer container);
    void ApplyInitializedRegistrations(IUnityContainer container);
}
```

**UPDATE 2**

```
public abstract class MyApplication : Application, IPlatformApplication {
  public IUnityContainer AppUnityContainer => _container;
  protected virtual void OnLaunched()
    {
        IActivityService activityService = new ActivityService(this);
        AppUnityContainer.RegisterInstance(activityService);

        AppUnityContainer.RegisterType<IRegistrar, PlatformRegistrar>();
}
```

}

Comment: What do you mean by *`I know I cannot create an object using this constructor`*

Comment: I checked their other files, and they have never directly called to constructor.

Comment: Most likely because it is injected by the DI container, which would be responsible for initializing the class

Comment: How can I call this method from my activity?

Comment: Update the question with the code you are actually trying to do.

Comment: Can you get access to the container from the activity?

Comment: Ok following the breadcrumbs. Where is `IRegistrar` being used. Are there any other references to  the container. In `App` maybe?

Comment: Yes it has refered. Please check the updated part

Comment: Where does `_container` come from? Code is incomplete. making it difficult to properly assess the problem and find potential solution.